# ASM - how do I write graphics straight to the screen

Tags: assembly

I have some old RISC OS assembly programmes I wrote a few years back and I want to port them to Raspberry Pi.

I ran Mode 28 and wrote output directly to the screen using the memory address where v-ram started -- i.e., I didn't use an SWI call.

Is there anyway to write directly to the screen on the Pi? What is the address and do I need to set a specific mode.

I am currently running Raspbian ... but can switch to RISC OS if that is easier

Cheers
John

Comment: I'd have thought RISC OS would be a more natural fit for RISC OS assembly.  How do you find out where the screen is located in memory and how do you access that address?  Are you using /dev/mem to access raw memory?

Comment: One other thing you could look into is [this set of tutorials here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/screen01.html). I've linked the first one in which you learn how to program graphics - but they're all very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

With Linux you could try the framebuffer interface. It can be memory mapped as a buffer where you write your data.